# GCMIntentService cast exception

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem when my GCMIntentService is called, an exception is thrown:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.test.GCMIntentService cannot be
>   cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

However my class does extend the GCMBaseIntentService, in fact my construct "ends" well (the super(SENDER_ID); is passed without issues) and the problem comes when exiting the constructor, I suspect when an internal class tries to cast the newly created instance of my extending class.

Code for reference if needed:

```
package com.adk.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import utilities.Logd;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private final String LOG_TAG = "Test";
    private final static String senderID = "66610078X85X";


    public GCMIntentService(){
        super("66610078X85X");
        Logd.i(LOG_TAG, "GCM passed");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorID) {
        Logd.e(LOG_TAG, errorID, null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        enviarNotificacion(arg0, intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String deviceID) {
        Registrar(arg0, deviceID);      
        Logd.i(LOG_TAG, "Registered");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Logd.i(LOG_TAG, "Unregistered");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing a [GCMBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/index.html?com/google/android/gcm/GCMBroadcastReceiver.html) to whatever you're passing the GCMIntentService to. You shouldn't need to inherit and override the name, since it looks like your intent service already has [the right name](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/client-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/GCMConstants.html#DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME).

Comment: I'm not passing to anything :S I just call GCMRegistrar.register(act, SENDER_ID); and the constructor is called, I think GCMRegistrar tries to cast it.

Comment: Intriguing. Have you called GCMBroadcastReceiver.checkManifest()?

Comment: yes, well I called GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(), should I post the manifest?

Comment: As long as it's not throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException, it doesn't seem necessary. I'm a bit stumped, though. The only thing I can think of is if in your manifest you have `<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMIntentService" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >` rather than `<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >`, but that seems improbable.

Comment: tually I just noticed I have  `<receiver android:name=".GCMIntentService" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >` But I think that's correct, isnt't it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html step 4 says otherwise. The way it all hangs together is that you point that bit of your manifest at their BroadcastReceiver, and their BroadcastReceiver will then load your IntentService.

Comment: You're right, I don't really know how I missed that, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates the framework is trying to access your GCMIntentService at:

```
 com.test.test.GCMIntentService
```

But your source code has the package name set to:

```
package com.adk.test;
```

I think changing your package name to `com.test.test` should work.

Or, if you prefer to stick with com.adk.test.GCMIntentService, then modify your AndroidManifest.xml's GCM receiver to:

```
<receiver android:name="com.adk.test.GCMIntentService" .... />
```